# dusk ml logisticregression throws this error: "NotImplementedError: Can not add intercept to array with unknown chunk shape"

Tags: python, nlp, dask, dask-ml

Hello i am new to dusk Ml, i have been trying to use dask ml to train a logistic regression model to predict tweet sentiment. I have converted a pandas dataframe to a dask dataframe. After that i performed train test split. After that i used hashing vectorizer on X_train and X_test.
i executed the line `Train_X_vect.compute().shape` to check the shape and it returned `(180224, 7000)` where else `y_train.compute().shape` returned `(180224,)`
Whenever I try, to fit them in a logistic regression model i get an error saying "cannot add intercept to array with unknown chunk"
this is my code:

```
from dask_ml.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df,npartitions=4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dask_df ["preprocess"], dask_df ["target"],random_state=42)
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=7000)
vectorizer.fit(X_train)
Train_X_vect = vectorizer.transform(X_train)
Test_X_vect = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(Train_X_vect,y_train)
```

I also used "fit_intercept = False" but then i wuld get this error: "IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2"

Please could you tell me what i am doing wrong, and how should I fix it?
Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Right now `LogisticRegression` requires that the Dask Array passed to it has known chunk sizes (see `Train_X_vect.chunks` or `.shape`). This restriction might be lifted in the future, but in the meantime convert to known chunks with `Train_X_vect.compute_chunk_sizes()` prior to `lr.fit`.

Comment: x_chunk = Train_X_vect.compute_chunk_sizes()

y_chunk = y_train.compute_chunk_sizes()

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_chunk,y_chunk)

Comment: this throws an error for y_chunk : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'compute_chunk_sizes'

Comment: could you help me fix this